# USE INDEX (PRIMARY) in mysql query, but getting a wrong syntax error?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to speed up a mySQL query by making it use the index, but for some reason it's telling me that the syntax is wrong. I can't figure out why, though. Any ideas?

All I did was add "USE INDEX (PRIMARY)"

```
SELECT a.listing_id FROM db_listings USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
a LEFT JOIN db_users u ON u.user_id=a.owner_id WHERE a.active=1 GROUP BY a.listing_id
```

Comment: Won't mySQL use the primary index by default?

Comment: try replacing `primary`with the actual index column names. see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the table alias `a` before the USE INDEX clause.

Comment: +1, that's what the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html) says.